# Null GetLine1Number

Tags: basic4android

```
Dim p As PhoneId
Dim ph As Phone 
numPhone = p.GetLine1Number
```

I need another way that extract the number phone.

Im using number phone for register our app, that was sell on market.
As market mercant, when our app was suspended we only have that way to re-register app for the people that bought it.

Using GetLine1Number, works for us. but for example a see on a S Galaxy S and SII doesnt show anything. On our Optimus 2x works fine.

Is there another way to get the phone number?

Using stackoverflow for first time like Erel said ;)

PS: Optimus running 2.3 and S and SII too! ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSISDN : Is it a SIM Card Data? Why all The Provided Function (from Blackberry and Android) to fetch MSISDN not reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695601/msisdn-is-it-a-sim-card-data-why-all-the-provided-function-from-blackberry-a)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is another way to get the phone number. You can use [PhoneId.GetDeviceId](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/phone.html#phoneid) if the line number is not available to get a unique id.

Comment: I know that the best way is use GetdeviceID but on Android Market from customers is the only way to follow whats customers did adquire the app.