# Android: get user phone number by SMS or Google Account

Tags: android, sms, phone-number

In my Android app I'm trying to get the user's phone number. I tried the TelephonyManager solution but here in Europe 90% of the SIM cards have that field blank, so the function returns NULL.

I think I could get the user's phone number searching for sent SMS or by querying the Google account. For the SMS method, I tried to load the content provider sms/sent, but the only address field I can extract is the phone number of the person the user sent the SMS to.

For the Google account I have no idea on what to do.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to do it might be to try a few different things and see if they agree.

Comment: One point: I don't think it's necessary to have a Google account to use an Android phone, so that's unlikely to be a foolproof method.

Comment: This is right. I'm aware i will never succeed in extracting the user phone number in the 100% of cases. I'm just building a function that tries as many methods as possible. Actually my function try to extract it from the SIM, if it fail the fucntion could try the SMS method and as last chance the Google account method... it is just to improve the probability of succeed for this goal.

Comment: See my answer here that expands on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695601/msisdn-is-it-a-sim-card-data-why-all-the-provided-function-from-blackberry-a/11135551#11135551

Comment: Hi alex, if your method works - can you please post your code here? thanks!

Comment: Hi @Erez . i'm sorry but i haven't found a working solution for the problem... sorry.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but any updates on a solution Alex? as we are in the same situation!

Comment: @SamPalmer Sorry... haven't actually found any solution.

Comment: No worries, we came to the same conclusion and have had to build in sms authentication on application install instead. Cheer though, such an annoying issue!

Comment: Do you intend something like sending an SMS to the user with a code like in verification email?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber() {
  TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
  mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

Try this, I'm from Poland, and it works well.

Comment: Dear, i wrote in my first line that i already tried this solution and here in my country this return NULL because the SIM have the phone number field set to <EMPTY> by the provider...

Answer (score 0):

The solution: The package name of the manifest is de.org.limindo.limindo2 but the package of the apk is de.org.limindo2 .....