# Not able to get the SIM number when I use Airtel provider SIM card in Android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am working in my application and fetching phone number using the method:

```
TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager)appContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        number = phoneManager.getLine1Number();
```

It is working well and good with all the SIM card, but getting problem in Airtel provider SIM card.
I am getting blank while trying with this SIM card.

I don't know why Android API is dealing differently with different providers. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the [MSISDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN) number is not filled on the SIM card by the operator. unfortunately nothing you can do about that.

Thread with some insight on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695601/msisdn-is-it-a-sim-card-data-why-all-the-provided-function-from-blackberry-a)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Telephony Manager;If at all you not found the contact no. of user; You can get Sim Serial Number of Sim Card and Imei No. of Android Device by using the same Telephony Manager Class...

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Import:

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
```

Use the below code:

```
 TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

     // get IMEI
     imei = tm.getDeviceId();

     // get SimSerialNumber
     simSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```