# MSISDN Detection Mobility -

Tags: android, blackberry, msisdn

I need to get the MSISDN number of my the device(Blackberry primarily ) on which app is running. I know it can be done using wap. Just wanted to know is there any common webservice by using which i can get the msisdn number. Or i need to create one. Also is there any way by using which i can get the msisdn number.

Referred link - [MSISDN : Is it a SIM Card Data? Why all The Provided Function (from Blackberry and Android) to fetch MSISDN not reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695601/msisdn-is-it-a-sim-card-data-why-all-the-provided-function-from-blackberry-a)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to get msisdn and it depends on mobile operators.

While one operator provide msisdn via http header with authorized ip and domain, another one provide msisdn via it's own web service.

There may be another ways to get msisdn, but i don't think there is a common web service.

Nevertheless, you can try to get msisdn via following http headers.

- X-MSISDN
- X_MSISDN
- HTTP_MSISDN
- HTTP_X_MSISDN
- HTTP_X_FH_MSISDN
- HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID

Comment: ohhh... got reply after year... have already got ride of above query..Anyways thanks.